# Integrating Flash with facebook

Tags: flash, magento, facebook

Am new to Facebook development....

Am developing magento with flash store. We completed all the steps From checkout, payment, order and invoice creation by flash through magento. its running successfully.

Now the client come up with requirement of integrating that flash to facebook. So till now when they try to access flash. we ask login and based on credential allow the user to shop the products.

There is facebook connect module in magento. by this user can access the magento products by facebook account in html store or normal store.

now what they are asking is add this flash as apps in facebook. From facebook if the user access the aplication. we need to take the facebook session as user session and allow to purchase and checkout the products.

Is any one worked on this type of project. or any one get the facebook session into flash.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy ways to pass the facebook session into flash: The Javascript SDK and the PHP sdk. 
To use either, you will create a new application in facebook using the developer app.

After that you can use the example code for the app that you can find in the PHP SDK, or the javascript SDK.

1. Add this app first
   Facebook Developer App:
   https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2345053339
2. Choose an SDK
   Links to SDK
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

To integrate with flash, you can pass the variables from PHP using flashvars.
To integrate with flash and javascript, you use ExternalInterface, and a javascript function.